# Get list out all Azure services in a subscription using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, cloud

I have an azure subscription and I'm trying to write a powershell script to automatically get a list of all the resources (VMs, Storage Accounts, Databases, etc) that I currently have in my subscription.  Is there any way to perform this.

Comment: Yes.
(Please show us what you have tried)

Answer (score 4):

The PowerShell Cmdlet you're looking for is [`Get-AzureRMResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt652503.aspx). It will list all the resources in your Azure Subscription. It will provide the name, resource id, type, resource group name and location for each and every resource in your Subscription.

Comment: Don't forget to add [`Login-AzureRmAccount`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/#authenticate-with-password---powershell) before that command though

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update; Find-AzureRMResource will actually get you all the resources in a given scope eg. everything in a resource group or subscription. Which may be more useful if you don't want to specify multiple parameters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/find-azurermresource?view=azurermps-4.2.0

Answer (score -1):

To take this a step further, if you have multiple subscriptions, you can get all resources from all subscriptions using the following command:

```
get-azurermsubscription | Foreach-object{set-azurermcontext -Subscription $_.SubscriptionId; get-azurermresource}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. It doesn't like how you are setting the subscription.